# What does "spore" mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What does ***spore*** mean in [this quote](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/wo...a-9910635.html) from *The Independent?*

> "In the fight against rhino poaching, the dog's nose has proved invaluable in finding poachers," he said. "Our human trackers, which rely solely on their eyesight, cannot see **spore** due to environmental conditions - be that very thick vegetation or rocky outcrops. The dog's sense of smell has proven superior in scenarios like that."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The writer of that article (or the person they are quoting) has used 'spore' where they should have said **spoor**, which Oxforddictionaries.com defines [thus:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/spoor)

> NOUN
>
> The track or scent of an animal:
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *they searched around the hut for a spoor*
>
> *the trail is marked by wolf spoor*
>
> *As it was vanishing on the hill-tops, a group of enthusiasts preferred to forgo arguing and, grasping their spears, were soon busy tracking its spoor on the soft soil in the crevices among the boulders.*
>
> *The spoor was fresher, and the side trails of the leopard's continued presence in the area told them they were approaching her lair.*
>
> *On the windowsill, the pigeon is gone, but it has left its spoor.*

Comment: The writer also used "which" instead of "who". //shudder

Comment: @Marthaª - *Mon dieu!* So they have!